# How to get employee detail by userId in Python/Falcon

Tags: python, falcon

I am new to Python/**[Falcon](https://falconframework.org/)**. How to get employee details by `userId` in Python?

## falcontry.py

**Falcon example:**

```
import falcon
import json 

class ThingsResource: 

    def on_get(self, req, resp): 
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200 

        fp = open("jsonparser.json","r") 
        json_str = fp.read() 

        print json_str json_content = json.loads(json_str)
        json_content = json.dumps(json_content) 

        print json_content resp.body = (json_content)

api = falcon.API() 
things = ThingsResource() 
api.add_route('/Employees/userId/{id}', things)
```

what i am doing wrong here?

jsonparser.json
**Employees:**

```
{ "Employees" : [{
        "userId":"RUPAK",
        "jobTitleName":"Developer",
        "firstName":"ABC",
        "lastName":"Irani",
        "preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
        "employeeCode":"E1",
        "region":"CA",
        "phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
        "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com"
    }]

}
```

Comment: `id = t.get('Employees')[0].get('userId')` I think you can pretty much take it from here. Just declare that `on_get` method and loop through `Employees` till you get to your desired result.

Comment: @iamdanchiv thank you for your answer. but could you explain briefly?

Answer (score 0):

**Your JSON/Dict:**

```
t =  { "Employees" : [ {
            "userId":"RUPAK",
            "jobTitleName":"Developer",
            "firstName":"ABC",
            "lastName":"Irani",
            "preferredFullName":"Romin Irani",
            "employeeCode":"E1",
            "region":"CA",
            "phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
            "emailAddress":"romin.k.irani@gmail.com" }
            ]
    }
```

**Employees Class:**

```
class Employees():

    def on_get(self, json, userID):
        for x in json.get('Employees'):
            if x.get('userId') == userID: 
                print x


empl = Employees()
empl.on_get(t, 'RUPAK')
```

**Output:**

`$ python pytest.py
{'emailAddress': 'romin.k.irani@gmail.com', 'phoneNumber': '408-1234567', 'jobTitleName': 'Developer', 'firstName': 'ABC', 'lastName': 'Irani', 'preferredFullName': 'Romin Irani', 'employeeCode': 'E1', 'userId': 'RUPAK', 'region': 'CA'}`

Let me know if you need more details on the approach. As it stands, it is pretty hard to understand what you are looking for, because of the lack of information/formatting in your question.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I can not post with formatting. can you tell me my mistakes?
import falcon
import json

class ThingsResource:
 
    def on_get(self, req, resp, json, userId):
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200 
        fp = open("jsonparser.json","r")
        x = fp.read()
   for x in json.get('Employees'):
          if x.get('userId') == userID:
     print x
  json_content = json.loads(x)
        json_content1 = json.dumps(json_content)
        resp.body = (json_content1)
        
api = falcon.API()
things = ThingsResource()
api.add_route('/Employees/RUPAK', things)

Comment: I have connected database(db=Employee, table=Detail) this way in python. File name db_connection.py . Now I want to (on_get and on_post) value by user_id  that database in python falcon

    import MySQLdb
    
    try:
     db = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost',
           user = 'root',
           passwd = '***',
           db = 'Employee'
           )
    except Exception as e:
     sys.exit('We cant get into the database')
     
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Detail')
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    
    print result

Answer (score 0):

As per your most recent comment, I'm assuming that you have a database of `Employee` with a table named `Detail` and you want the user to pass the `userId`. That will be achieved by requesting the URL http://www.yourdomain.com/Employees?userId=RUPAK

If that is the case, you can read `userId` from `req` object by using `req.get_params()` and query your database using a `SELECT` statement with `WHERE` clause. Your modified code is as followed:

```
import falcon
import json 
import MySQLdb

class ThingsResource: 
    def on_get(self, req, resp): 
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200 
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = '***', db = 'Employee' ) 
        cursor = db.cursor() 

        userId=req.get_params('userId')
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Detail WHERE userId='+userId) 
        result = cursor.fetchone() 
        print result
        resp.body = json.dumps(result) 

api = falcon.API() 
things = ThingsResource() 
api.add_route('/Employees', things)
```

If this resolves your problem then please marks "Answered" otherwise let me know if you need further assistance.